# SQL: Count Distinct and Combine Similarly-Named

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

**Language**: T-SQL
**Server**: SQL Server 2014

I have a table of PCs and would like to get a count of each PC by the manufacturer. That is simple, but when pulling the data from each PC some older HP computers report their manufacturer as "Hewlett-Packard" while newer machines report their manufacturer as "HP". I'd like to combine these into "HP". The query that doesn't do any replacement/combining is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT f_assetmanufacturer AS 'Manufacturer',
    COUNT(DISTINCT f_assettagID) AS 'Number of Each'
FROM tb_assets
GROUP BY f_assetmanufacturer
```

Sample output based on current query:

```
Manufacturer      Number of Each
Dell Inc.         10
Hewlett-Packard   6
HP                6
```

Desired Output:

```
Manufacturer      Number of Each
Dell Inc.         10
HP                12
```

How can the query be rewritten to combine "HP" and "Hewlett-Packard" COUNTs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use REPLACE on the manufacturer column to get the formatted string you need.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), REPLACE(Mfg, 'Hewlett-Packard', 'HP')
FROM dbo.SO41271540
GROUP BY REPLACE(Mfg, 'Hewlett-Packard', 'HP')
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I had tried doing a "Replace" in the SELECT statement but it would still only return "6" instead of "12". I didn't realize it was also required in the GROUP BY statement. Can you shed any light on whether this option is preferable over @jhilden 's response below other than being shorter?

Comment: My solution is only simpler if you need to perform a single replace. If you need to replace multiple names, you would need to chain REPLACE statements. In that case, @jhilden's solution will be far more elegant. And if you need to routinely update your manufacturer mapping, then creating the mapping table like John Cappelletti suggests will be even better. Use the simplest tool that gets the job done.

Comment: Fortunately, the necessity to expand the number of replacements is quite minimal. At this time only "HP" and "Hewlett-Packard" are the same despite the database currently having 24 different manufacturers on over 5000 PCs. Other manufacturers all appear to be consistent in how they report themselves to the OS.

Comment: @Beem  This is a perfectly valid solution for a quick fix.  But it has been my experience that IF something can change, it eventually will.  Today it's HP, tomorrow it may be Toshiba.  Do you really want to be chasing that cat?

Comment: @John I have about 10 years of data, and I can only find the problem with "HP" and "Hewlett-Packard". While the possibility always exists that other manufacturers may change their name, historically it hasn't been a problem and should I notice a pattern I will happily create a mapping table to assist with future queries.

Comment: @Beems Fair enough.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement.  Add as many additional case clauses as needed.

```
SELECT 
    CASE f_assetmanufacturer 
    WHEN 'Hewlett-Packard' THEN 'HP'
    ELSE f_assetmanufacturer 
    END
, COUNT(DISTINCT f_assettagID)
FROM dbo.Code c
GROUP BY CASE f_assetmanufacturer 
    WHEN 'Hewlett-Packard' THEN 'HP'
    ELSE f_assetmanufacturer 
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for a mapping table just to keep it out of code and more dynamic as time goes on.  For example:

```
Declare @YourResults table (Manufacturer varchar(50),[Number of Each] int)
Insert into @YourResults values
('Dell Inc.',         10),
('Hewlett-Packard',   6),
('HP',                6)

Declare @Maping table (MapFrom varchar(50),MapTo varchar(50))
Insert Into @Maping values 
('Hewlett-Packard','HP'),
('Hewlett-Packard Inc.','HP')


Select Manufacturer= IsNull(B.MapTo,Manufacturer)
      ,[Number of Each] = sum([Number of Each])
 From  @YourResults A
 Left Join  @Maping B on (MapFrom=A.Manufacturer)
 Group By IsNull(B.MapTo,Manufacturer)
```

Returns

```
Manufacturer    Number of Each
Dell Inc.       10
HP              12
```

Comment: While for the sake of this query I will likely not have to expand it beyond the combining of "HP" and "Hewlett-Packard", your example here is very insightful as I can think of a number of other uses for this where I may have similar issues in the near future. Thank you for the well-thought-out response.

Comment: @Beems Fair enough.  I just wanted it on your radar.  Quick story.  One of my clients introduced a new Risk Rating 6W (or 6 Watch essentially a 6.5)  They had to review thousands of reports and countless lines of code.  I on the other hand, only had to add one record into my mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

This query will do the job, however it is hard-coded:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT REPLACE(f_assetmanufacturer, 'Hewlett-Packard', 'HP') AS 'Manufacturer',
    COUNT(DISTINCT f_assettagID) AS 'Number of Each'
FROM tb_assets
GROUP BY f_assetmanufacturer
```

The nicer solution would be to have a "master" manufacturer lookup table that you could join onto, and a foreign key column within `tb_assets` (ManufacturerId for example) that you can refer to.

Comment: Fortunately, the necessity to expand the number of replacements is quite minimal. At this time only "HP" and "Hewlett-Packard" are the same despite the database currently having 24 different manufacturers on over 5000 PCs. Other manufacturers all appear to be consistent in how they report themselves to the OS.